# Showing Exception error for the given code snippet

Tags: java, exception

I'm working on a code in which an input String is taken and an input character is taken. the code will calculate the percentage occurrence of that character in that String. the code is given below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class apple{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i,j,l=0;
        float m;
        char k;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String");
        String str = in.nextLine();
        j=str.length();
        System.out.println("Enter the character to be found");
        char s = in.next(".").charAt(0);
        for(i=0;i<=j;i++){
            k = str.charAt(i);
            if(k == s){
                l++;
            }
        }
        m= l/j;
        m=m*100;
        System.out.println("percent character in String is "+m);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception/error is it showing?

Comment: And the exception being? Saying "for no reason" doesn't help. Please paste the complete stack trace in the question.

Comment: Nothing happens for "no reason" in programming. Ever.

Answer (score 2):

Change your loop to

```
for(i = 0 ;i < j ; i++)
```

Otherwise, if your String has a length of `4` (so the last index is `3`), it will try to reach index `4` and throw an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= j; i++) {
```

and this is throwing an `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:`

because you are not considering that the element goes from 0 to lengt-1

instead you should do:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your for-loop to `for (i=0;i<j;i++)`. We can not access the element at array size position because Java array uses 0-based index

Answer (score 0):

The first character of a String is '0', the last is yourString.length()-1, so change your loop to

```
for( i = 0 ; i < j ; i++ ){
    k = str.charAt(i);
    if(k == s){
         l++;
    }
}
```

It'll work ;)